# Upgrading Internet Explorer 8 to 10 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

Can you guys help me in upgrading Internet Explorer 8 to Internet Explorer 10. Even I tried the downloading the IE 10. it is also failed to install and shows a error of you can't install Windows 2008R1 Server or Windows 7. My system configuration are Windows 7 Ultimate, 32 bit Machine. RAM: 4GB Processor: Intel Core i5

Comment: Where did you download from?

Comment: Microsofts website

Comment: It'd be better if you post a screenshot of the full error message

Comment: Why don't just use Windows Update?

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, create a zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, Dropbox or a different free cloud service) and post a link here.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend windows update. If this doesn't work, try downloading IE 10, then uninstalling IE from control panel, navigating to your downloads folder and installing IE10 from scratch?

But since Microsoft are discontinuing Internet Explorer, I would also suggest that now may be a good time to try out a new browser. Google Chrome or Firefox are the most popular and you can export bookmarks from IE to either of those without too much hassle if I remember correctly.

Comment: Microsoft isn't discontinuing Internet Explorer.  The browser being called `Spartan` is actually IE and uses the same engine Trident just without the compatibility modes enable and uses the new dll instead of the old dll.